# to select content controls in word doc using VBScript

Tags: checkbox, vbscript, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have a word document which has multiple checkboxes/radio buttons at different places in the doc, which needs to be enabled according to the UserInputs (which I plan through InputBox instead of dropdown). Kindly let me know how this can be achieved programatically using a VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

Say, I have added 4 content control (checkbox) in word document. Hence, the below lines will detect the content control on a first one encountered basis based on userinput

```
Reboot_Y_N = MsgBox ("Do you require reboot (Y/N)?",vbQuestion + vbYesNo,"Reboot")
If Reboot_Y_N = vbYes Then
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(1).Checked = True
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(3).Checked = True
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(5).Checked = True
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(7).Checked = True
      Else
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(2).Checked = True
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(4).Checked = True
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(6).Checked = True
    ObjDocImp.ContentControls.Item(8).Checked = True
End If
```